# Using substitution to solve $ \left( x^{2} +y^{2}\right)\frac{dy}{dx} =2xy$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

$$
\left( x^{2} +y^{2}\right)\frac{dy}{dx} =2xy$$

Let

$$y=ux,\ u=u( x)$$

$$u+x\frac{du}{dx} =\frac{2x^{2} u}{x^{2} +x^{2} u^{2}} =\frac{2u}{1+u^{2}}$$

$$\int \frac{1+u^{2}}{u-u^{3}} du=\int \frac{１}{x} dx+C$$

$$\int \left(\frac{1}{u} +\frac{1}{1-u} -\frac{1}{1+u}\right) du=\ln x+C$$

$$\ln( u) -\ln( 1-u) -\ln( 1+u) =\ln x+C$$

$$\ln\left(\frac{u}{1-u^{2}}\right) =\ln x+C$$

$$\frac{u}{1-u^{2}} =Cx$$

And then I don't know how to convert it into $u(x)$. Is it better to solve this problem by the solution of Exact equation? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $$
> \frac{u}{1-u^{2}} =Cx\\$$

Arrange terms, you get
$$u^2+\frac{1}{Cx}u-1=0$$

Solve this quadratic equation, you get

$$u=\frac{-\frac{1}{Cx}\pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{C^2x^2}+4}}{2}$$